# generate link to upploaded file by specific user

Tags: php, mysql

This image show up what I want to do.

[IMG]http://i52.tinypic.com/2ec1942.jpg[/IMG]

The code by Marc B did not work properly, since it still try to open any arbitrary file, bypassing the value from the UserID field.

Sorry for the inconvenience, please note I am just a novice to PHP & MySQL.

Comment: What do you want: display a link or open the file? Please clarify!

Comment: If you have this User_ID, just replace `$filename= "$updir/12345678.pdf";` with `$filename= "$updir/$User_ID.pdf";`

Answer (score 0):

Given a script address of something like `download.php?userID=12345678`:

```
<?php

$updir = "upload/"
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$filename = "{$updir}/{$userID}.pdf"

if (!is_readable($file)) then
    die("File is not readable or does not exist");
}

header(...)
header(...)
readfile($filename);
```

Of course, please note that this is highly insecure. the userID parameter is inserted without any consideration as to what it might contain. Using this setup, a malicious user can download any file on your server if they know what its path/filename are.